# React Redirect with a parameter

Tags: reactjs, redirect

I am working on a project. I want to preform a onClick method that redirect to another page and pass a parameter. But the Redirect method does not work even without pass the parameter. Could anyone take a look what is wrong with my code?

In my app.js, I have code to switch route:

```
<Router>
   <Switch>
        <Route path= "/Home">
           <Home/>
          </Route>
          <Route path= "/Projects">
           <Projects/>
          </Route>
          <Route path= "/Results">
           <Results/>
          </Route>
    </Switch>
 </Router>
```

In my component, I have:

```
function Search() {
  const [searchTerm, setTerm] = useState("");

  function handleChange(event) {
    setTerm(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleClick(event) {

  if (searchTerm.length > 0) {
    return(
 
      <Redirect
      to={{
        pathname: "/Results",
        state: {searchTerm}
      }}
    />
    
    );
  }

  event.preventDefault();
}


return (
  <div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid justify-content-end">
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input onChange={handleChange} value={searchTerm} class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
          <button onClick={handleClick} class="btn btn-outline-success">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little change, your code works well.

Instead of using `Redirect` component (Route), You need to do a simple change route with `history.push` method in this way:

```
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

function Search() {
  const [searchTerm, setTerm] = useState("");

  function handleChange(event) {
    setTerm(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleClick(event) {
    if (searchTerm.length > 0) {
      history.push({
        pathname: '/Results',
        state: {searchTerm}
      })
    }
  }

  // rest of the codes ...
}
```

Now in your `<Results/>` component, you can consume this state:

```
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';

function Results () {
  const location = useLocation();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const searchTerm = location.state.searchTerm
    console.log(searchTerm)
  }, [])

  // rest of the codes ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Redirect` won't work if you return it from calling a function. If you want to get to `/results` page using `Redirect` you can create a new state:

`const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);`

and set this state to `true` if the input value meets the required conditions `searchTerm.length > 0`. Then, you can use conditional rendering to add `Redirect` to your return statement

```
function handleClick() {

  if (searchTerm.length > 0) {
    setRedirect(true)
  }
}

return (
    <>
      {redirect && (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/Results"
          }}
        />
      )}
      <input
        type="text"
        value={query}
        onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Search</button>
    </>
  );
```

[Working example with Redirect](https://codesandbox.io/s/redirect-y1wvu?file=/src/App.js:427-743)

The second way is to use hook `useHistory()`:

```
const history = useHistory();

function handleClick() {

  if (searchTerm.length > 0) {
    history.push("/Results");
  }
}
```

[Example with useHistory](https://codesandbox.io/s/usehistory-dqpdo?file=/src/App.js:370-395)

Comment: Hi Dmitriif, Thank you so much for your help! I will try your solution!